How to ensure perfectly perpendicular cuts [to a countertop] with a skilsaw?
I will be ripping a corian-like countertop with a triple-cut-grind TCG 7 inch blade using a skilsaw and a clamped guide.  A perfectly vertical cut is critical. While the skilsaw guide is straight enough for everyday use, I am not confident that:

the guide is reliable for a truly vertical cut
while I am ripping the countertop that I can confidently keep the saw perfectly flush. I do not have a particularly steady grip/push and can use some help here.

I am looking for tips on how to minimize the variance on the cut from purely perpendicular to the surface.

Most tools recommend using a square to make sure 90 degrees is actual.  The quality of the stiffness/locking of the guide will help to maintain the cut.  If the guide bends by hand, maybe get a better saw.  For one cut, renting a better saw makes sense.

keep spending money till you can get the result you need.  maybe a track saw can get you close enough to vertical maybe that's not good enough.  On the other hand when leaning on the fence it could be argued that I am still "truly vertical".   How good do you actually need it to be?

When you say "corian like", tells me it is not Corian. So is it able to be cut with toothed blades?

Best practices would have you cutting with two hands on the saw -- back handle and front. You might consider how it feels to have one hand on the back and the other hand holding the base of the saw down and against the guide. (And I am, of course, talking about pushing down on the wide side of the base.)

The guide does nothing for "perfectly vertical" - that's the setting of the blade to the baseplate of the saw, and should be checked with a square, as the graduations on the saw's scale are typically both crude and often unreliable. Then you have to hold the saw's baseplate down to the surface so it's holding the blade at that angle.
The guide helps with making a straight cut along the material - depending on its design that may require ensuring that the saw's baseplate edge is held to it as well as the baseplate's bottom being held to the surface of the material, or there may be a mechanical connection of the edge of the guide to the baseplate.

Fair enough: and I will check the saw with a square as you say.  However I also intended to imply/indicate that just keeping the saw flush (and thus correct in all three dimensions including vertically) is not always as easy as I would think.

Well, that (with a portable circular saw) comes down to "practice makes perfect" (whether using a saw, or a router as @Jack suggests for your final cut.) Or choosing a different method altogether (e.g. have someone cut it on a CNC machine that does not depend on humans holding things.)

So you don't go into the cut "blind" not knowing what to expect as a result, if the material is long enough for an extra cut, off set the straight edge an inch or two and cut there. Check that cut for squareness. This will also let you get the feel for making the cut.
Then reset the guide in the proper spot to make the cut, and go for it.
If there is room to to a few of these, use it for practice.
FWIW, whenever I cut Corian, I cut it rough with a circular saw or table saw, and made the last perfect cut with a router and straightedge.
If you must only use a circular saw, cut it from the back side. If cutting from the face side, most surely the fresh cut corner will be chipping as it is cut. That's one of the reasons why the router for the last pass.

I was certainly planning to do a couple of "dry-runs" (cutting in the excess area and checking the quality)  to perfect whatever method is used (before the final "this is it" cut)

When I was doing Corian et al solid surface on the assembly bench, it was always finish-cut with a router and sharp bit. The saw blade cuts in the solid surface from the sliding table saw we used to rough cut still showed teeth marks scored into the slab. A router for the final cut is super important.

Skilsaw may not be the best tool for the jib.
There are various right-angle guides available. Haven't used them so no opinion.
I usually just use a square to draw a reference line and cut on that. Depending on your needs and skills, that might not suffice
Cutting at a precise right angle is one of the things (properly set up) miter saws and table saws are designed for. Or panel saws.
A lumberyard may be willing to cut newly purchased materials; first cut is often free. Up to you to decide if you trust their accuracy to meet your needs.
With thinner material, you can cut oversized and then use a trim router to take off excess.

Skilsaw vs table saw:  This is an eight foot one-hundred or so pounds  piece and I'm working by myself.

Granted. Which is why I went through all the other possible alternatives I could immediately think of. Presumably too large for miter saw too. I think my instinct would be warehouse cut with panel saw rather than on site, possibly a touch oversized and doing final trim onsite with router...  But the best too depends on what you have available and what you have experience with and what you're willing to invest.


invest
Yea i'm at about $100 to $200 level of allowed investment here: otherwise i'd get one of those long channel jigs in which the saw is locked laterally and vertically and thus can only travel in the parallel direction - ensuring a perfect cut.  I'm going to try to do the job without that equipment first but if it goes too poorly then $150 or so here we come.


Have you asked the other construction folks, and/or the folks selling you the raw countertop stock, how they'd handle it? Have you checked the manufacturer's website to see if they have any tips?

Mostly I hear about taking the piece to a warehouse. I'm not doing that: I'm on a pretty strict budget on this.

Track saws are pretty nice. Just sayin’
